# Issue while exporting site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server, central-administration, export

We are facing an error while exporting a site:

> The object of type Web and URL that was configured as part of the Export Settings does not exist.

Verified the below options:

- Ran the Powershell command.
- Ran the stsadm command.
- Tried manually by using Central administration.
- Checked for orphan lists in the site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Export-SPWeb and Import-SPWeb?

We were trying to export and import a list with stsadm which failed, but Export/Import SPWeb worked fine.

This worked for a list export/import:

Export-SPWeb "https://sharepoint.portal.com/test" –ItemUrl "Lists/ApprovalTasks" –Path "C:\QuoteApprovalTasks.cmp"
Import-SPWeb "https://sharepoint.portal.com/test" –Path "C:\ApprovalTasks.cmp"

-ItemUrl might have to be some different parameter, check TechNet for Export and Import-SPWeb